# How to fetch value from an ExtensionDataObject of a wcf reponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service which returns ExtensionDataObject during runtime as attached snapshot:
Im struck with fetching value for these objects. Could anyone please help here:

Have tried with below code using reflection, which throws Parameter count missing exception

```
  List<System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject> extData = temp.Select(x => x.ExtensionData).ToList();
             var GetCountry = extData.GetType().GetProperties();

              string Country = string.Empty;
                foreach (var property in GetCountry)
                {
                    string name = property.Name;
                    object value = property.GetValue(extData, null);
                    if (name == "Country")
                        Country = value.ToString();

                }
```

[image]

Comment: just add those property to the class whih is `x` object - they will be deserialized automatically

Comment: I cannot modify service class as its third party service.What else could be alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The `Extensiondataobject` field is generated to control the data contract incompatibility between the server and the client, so it will return a field named `extensiondataobject`. In other words, your client data contract implements the `IExtensionDataObject` interface.

```
    [DataContract(Namespace="abcd")]
    public class Product: IExtensibleDataObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get ; set ; }
}
```

If we capture this request through Fiddle, you can even see all the data directly.
In a word, you only need to add the `Country` property to the Data class of X object. It will be deserialized automatically. This class should be your client-side data contract class, instead of the server-side data class.
[image]
Finally, it seems that the value of these fields is null. We should ensure that the server and client data contracts have the same namespace. It cannot be the default value(http://tempuri.org). As I defined above, this namespace attribute should be consistent with the server-side value.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.