# how to set value to ExtensionDataObject?

Tags: c#, wcf, properties

I'm trying to write Integration test for WCF service.

On the server I have class PersonalInfo, which has property FirstName.

But on the client this proxy class PersonalInfo has only ExtensionData property which type is ExtensionDataObject.

First I created object:

```
var updatedPersonalInfo = new PersonalInfo();
```

Then I try to set FirstName:

```
updatedPersonalInfo.ExtensionData.GetType().GetProperty("FirstName").SetValue(updatedPersonalInfo, "FirstName", null);
```

I get exception because ExtensionData is null.

How I can assign FirstName for PersonalInfo?

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482688/how-to-fetch-value-from-an-extensiondataobject-of-a-wcf-reponse), but related to getting properties from ExtensionDataObject.

Comment: Sounds to me like your client is out of date. Can you update it so it is in sync with the service and has all the necessary properties?

Comment: @JohnWu, I didn't get this object from server, I just created it in the test and wanted to submit request with test info.

Comment: Why would you create an object without the properties that you need?

Comment: @JohnWu, because I need such object for submitting update request. See relaled question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482688/how-to-fetch-value-from-an-extensiondataobject-of-a-wcf-reponse

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the personalinfo of the server-side has the property firstname, while the generated proxy class does not have the property firstname in the client-side, probably because the property of your server-side class does not add DataMember. This will cause you to generate a proxy class without this property.
The properties in the server-side personalinfo class should be as follows:

```
      [DataMember(Name = "firstName")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
```

Then you need to regenerate the service, update the service reference on the client-side and regenerate the proxy class.
The extensiondataobject is used to pass data back and forth between the old version of the data class and the new version of the data，Personalinfo class doesn't do any initialization on extensiondata, so it's null.

Comment: don't think I have permission for server changes, but I'll check